# Pictures of taxis in Karachi

Tags: data-request, public-transport, photographs

I am looking for pictures of taxis in Karachi.

If possible, at least a picture for each taxi company.

Pictures must be reusable in Wikipedia (compatible with Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0).

Wikimedia Commons does not seem to have any:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Taxis_by_country

Here is a non-free image showing how the typical yellow Karachi taxis look like: [image: Karachi taxis]

Answer (score 2):

With Google you can search for images and choose the general license terms. For specific companies you'd have to do a specific search.

Here is a search with "[Reuse with modification](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1063&bih=511&q=taxis+karachi&oq=taxis+karachi&gs_l=img.3...1505.3657.0.3880.13.9.0.4.0.1.251.1118.0j5j1.6.0.msedrc...0...1ac.1.58.img..9.4.691.lIVRhddBCK8#tbs=sur:fmc&tbm=isch&q=taxi+karachi)"

[image]

[Here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:RickshawPak.jpg) is one example of results, from Wikipedia.

[image]

Comment: I tried this before posting the question, but unfortunately only false positives came. All of the taxis that come out are actually taxis in India or neighbouring countries. The image you posted above is indeed in Karachi, but it is not what Karachi people would call a taxi, actually if I used this picture as an illustration of a Karachi taxi, I would sound insulting to local people (the illustration is in a document meant to be read by Karachi locals).

Comment: I edited my question to show what a typical Karachi taxi looks like.